# Serving react js app (using react-router) in 2 paths using nginx

Tags: nginx, reactjs, react-router

I have a react app that is using [react-router 2.0.0](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router). The react router routes are setup such that..

react App - localhost:3000/

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route name="homepage" path="/" component={App}>
        <IndexRoute component={Homepage} />
        <Route name="cat" path="cat/:catId" component={Catpage} />
    </Route>
</Router>
```

Currently I have configured nginx such that '/' mapped to this app.

```
location / {
    root /home/ubuntu/projects/app; }
```

Now I want to change the config such so as to serve this app from 2 different base paths. i.e.
abc.net/A will serve app AND
abc.net/B/C will also serve the same app

How do I configure the nginx server to do this without modifying the react router code? Is it possible at all?